# Why is the title of The Big Bang Theory not translated in Quebec?

Tags: title, distribution, the-big-bang-theory

In Quebec, the French speaking part of Canada, it is usual (and seems to be part of [Bill 101](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charter_of_the_French_Language) about the use of French Language in Quebec) to translate titles of movies and TV show into French. For example, *[Lost](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_:_Les_Disparus)* is known as *Perdus*, or *[How I met your mother](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_I_Met_Your_Mother)* becomes *Comment je l'ai rencontre*, etc...

But, at least according to [Wikipedia-fr](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory), The Big Bang Theory keeps its English title in Quebec. This is corroborated by this [article](http://quebec.huffingtonpost.ca/2014/11/12/mort-de-carol-ann-susi-la-mere-de-howard-wolowitz-dans-the-big-bang-theory_n_6144298.html) from The Huffington Post Quebec.

My question: is there any given (by the authors, by the network broadcasting the show in Quebec) reason explaining that the *The Big Bang Theory* is not called *La theorie du Big Bang* au Quebec?

Comment: It doesn't have the same "ring" to it? :P

Comment: @Paulster2: I didn't get it.

Comment: Sorry, was trying to be a little *tongue-in-cheek* there ... it's also why I left it as a comment and not an answer. Sometimes my humor is lost on others ... (my wife says I'm just not funny.)

Comment: My bad. I am not a native English speaker, so I didn't understand the joke.

Comment: Is there a translation for the actual theory of the Big Bang, the scientific term? Maybe it works like "internet" and other technical terms?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: In France French, we use the English expression Big Bang. Wikipedia does not give any translation in Canadian French, so I guess they use also Big Bang. No "Grande explosion" or "Grand Boum". Still remains the problem of not translating "theory".

Comment: Is this sitcom dubbed French when broadcast in Quebec?  I think they might only translate the titles to French when the show dialogue is dubbed. And even then, not 100% of the time, e.g. *Downtown Abbey*. But I'm not certain on this.

Comment: It is also called "The Big Bang Theory" in France. As Taladris commented, "Big Bang" is the only french expression for the scientific term, but they might have translated "theory" and changed the order of words to french order :"La Théorie du Big Bang", but they did not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually see anything in the Wikipedia article about Bill 101 (or in a brief perusal of the actual document) that **requires** film/tv/book titles (or even the series itself) to be translated into French (if you can find a specific section that does, please post it). I'm guessing this falls under Canadian free speech.

In fact, I can't even find a "view in French" option on the website for [CTV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTV_Television_Network) (the company that airs *The Big Bang Theory*)... the entire site is in English and doesn't have a way to access it in French... even the Montreal section of [City TV](http://www.citytv.com/montreal/) (the network that aired *How I Met Your Mother*) is in English and the title of the show is listed that way.

Comment: you can watch it in french here http://www.canalplus.fr/c-series/c-the-big-bang-theory/pid6595-bbt-la-serie.html

Comment: The question is about Quebec, but since I live in France I can give some extra information. The show itself is translated into french. Which is a pity because Raj's accent in french is far from being as funny as in english. Also Kripke's speech impairment is much less remarkable. The title of the show, however, is still "The Big Bang Theory", no attempt to translate at all. Though of course, "Big Bang" is never translated at all, even in "serious" science.